# PlotGoogleMaps -Need help in bubbleGoogleMaps

Tags: r

I am learning R and I love it so far. I am so impressed with one of the example provided in the "plotGoogleMaps" package. Is it possible to apply that my below example? please help.

The example I see in the package

```
    # Data preparation
    library(plotGoogleMaps)
    data(meuse)
    coordinates(meuse)<-~x+y
    proj4string(meuse) <- CRS('+init=epsg:28992')

    m<-bubbleGoogleMaps(meuse,zcol='zinc')

    m<-bubbleGoogleMaps(meuse,zcol='cadmium',layerName='Bubble plot - meuse',
                        colPalette=terrain.colors(5),strokeColor=&rdquo;)
```

I Would like to apply the above example map to my below data.
In my example sale = zinc (in above example). And I want to display my other attributes while I am highlighting my bubble.

```
  library(plotGoogleMaps)
    bubblechart = read.table(text="Itemcode,sale,name,longt,latit
                        101,1112,A,-89.6171,35.24992
                   105,1540,B,-90.0154,35.10510
                   106,2200,C,-89.5213,34.93277
                   111,1599,D,-86.8642,36.34807
                   113,4500,E,-86.6125,36.19958
                   114,3569,F,-90.4611,30.02196",
                   header=TRUE,sep=",")
```

Please help...

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `plotGoogleMaps`. If you look at the documentation `help(bubbleGoogleMaps)` will tell you that it requires an "object of SpatialPointsDataFrame-class with associated coordinate reference systems".  `meuse` is a "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
`class(meuse)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bubbleGoogleMaps()` requires you to transform your `bubblechart` data in a SpatialPointsDataFrame. For this you need to specify the coordinates and the reference system in which Longitude and Latitude were measured. There is a related GIS stackexchange question: [Converting geographic coordinate system in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45263/converting-geographic-coordinate-system-in-r).
See also the Wikipedia page of the [World Geodetic System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) (used by GPS).

## Inspect an existing SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
library(plotGoogleMaps)
data(meuse)
# meuse is a data frame
class(meuse)
# Specify coordinates and projection system
coordinates(meuse)<-~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS('+init=epsg:28992')
# meuse has become a "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
class(meuse)
# Which contains several objects
class(meuse@data)
class(meuse@coords)
summary(meuse@coords)
class(meuse@bbox)
class(meuse@proj4string)
help(SpatialPointsDataFrame)
# Convert meuse back to a data frame 
meusedtf <- as.data.frame(meuse)
```

## Create your own SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
# Set coordinates and reference system
coordinates(bubblechart) <- ~longt +latit
proj4string(bubblechart) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS 84
```

## Generate maps

```
m <- bubbleGoogleMaps(bubblechart, zcol='sale', max.radius = 20000)
```

[image]

Change the `max.radius` parameter to change bubble size. And change the `key.entries` parameter to set different boundaries on the sales values.

You can also display your sales bubbles as a R plot with:

```
plot(bubblechart)
points(bubblechart@coords, pch=21, cex=(bubblechart$sale)/1000, col="black", bg="blue")
bubble(bubblechart, "sale", maxsize = 2.5, main = "Sales in the US", key.entries = 2^(-1:4))
```

These R plots would look nicer if you add a map of the US states in the background to help identify the areas.

Comment: You explianed very well. However, I am not great in R. I would like to know I plot my data and I need some help here.

Comment: Copy the code of my answer in your R session and tell me what doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much...it is working now. You are wonderful!!! Much appreciated for all your help.